# Find the equation of the line tangent to the curve $y=\tan(\pi x/4)$ at (1,1)

Tags: calculus

When I take the derivative I get $\sec^2(\pi x/4)*pi/4$ but when I set it equal to zero I'm not sure how to solve. $\sec(\pi/x)=0$? Our teacher never went over how to solve that so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you trying to set it equal to zero?

Comment: Hint: The slope of the tangent is $\displaystyle\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have $$y=\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$$ and the first derivative is given by $$y'=\frac{1}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)}\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}$$
thus we have $$y'(1)=\frac{1}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}=m$$
the tangentline is now $$y=mx+n$$ to derive $n$ you can use that $$1=m\cdot 1+n$$

Answer (score 0):

$y=\tan(\frac{\pi x}{4})$ then $y' = \frac{\pi}{4} \sec^2(\frac{\pi x}{4})$.

To find the slope of that tangent line when $x=1$, simply evaluate $y'$ at $x=1$.

We find our slope to be $\frac{\pi}{4} \cdot (2) = \frac{\pi}{2} $.

You can then use the point slope formula to find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are doing wrong is setting the derivative to 0. You set a derivative to zero when you are looking for local maximums and minimums because the tangent line will be horizontal (having zero slope) at a local max or min. You want the tangent line. As you correctly got the slope of the tangent line at any given x is described by the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\pi}{4}\sec^2 (\pi x /4)$. you want the tangent line at $x=1$ ($\tan(\pi/4)=1$). 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x=1) = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \sec^2(\pi \cdot 1 /4) = \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot 2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
so the slope of your tangent line will be $\pi/2$ and you want the line to go through (1,1) sot in point slope form the equation will be 
$$y-1 = \frac{\pi}{2}(x-1)$$
Or in slope intercept form
$$y = \frac{\pi}{2}x +\frac{2-\pi}{2}$$